# primeng multiselect options box jumps to position 0,0 after pressing key in filter input

Tags: angular, primeng, multi-select

I use primeng multiselect control inside datatable.
When I put it inside ng-template pTemplate="editor", I get unexcepted behavior:

First time I open the multiselect, all is ok. But when I write any key inside the filter input, the options list jumps to position 0,0 of the screen.

Html code:

```
<ng-template *ngIf="itemProperty.widget=='multiSelect'&& itemProperty.name.indexOf('.')<0" let-row="rowData" pTemplate="editor">
                <p-multiSelect
                [displaySelectedLabel]="itemProperty.displaySelectedLabel? 'true':'false'"
                    [defaultLabel]="itemProperty.defaultLabel?'Choose':'...'"
                    optionLabel="Name"
                    [disabled]="itemProperty.editableOnlyInsert&&row.RowState!=3"
                    #con="ngModel"
                    [options]="itemProperty.options"
                    [(ngModel)]="row.Modules"
                    appendTo="body"                        [filter]="itemProperty.options&&itemProperty.options.length>5"
                    (onChange)="editItem(row,con,false,$event,true)" >
                </p-multiSelect>
            </ng-template>
```

After first time clicking on multiselect:

[image]

After writing something inside the filter input:

[image]

When I use pTemplate = "body", there is no problem.

Answer (score 0):

I resolve that by updating the `multiselect.ts` file from

```
components/multiselect/multiselect.ts

ngAfterViewChecked() {
        if (this.filtered) {
            this.filtered = false;
        }
    }
```

It working fine now it won't get to the corner of the screen.
Although its bad to modified file in the module, I guess they will fix it up in next release.

Comment: The meaning of this code is that primeng will not change position of the box when the content changed. maybe it works for you, but when the box open from bottom to top, and the list will be filtered, the box will stay in the original position, a few pixel above the input.

Answer (score 0):

DataTable is deplicated. You can use with turbotable or you can try this (delete appendTo="body")

```
<p-multiSelect
            [displaySelectedLabel]="itemProperty.displaySelectedLabel? 'true':'false'"
                [defaultLabel]="itemProperty.defaultLabel?'Choose':'...'"
                optionLabel="Name"
                [disabled]="itemProperty.editableOnlyInsert&&row.RowState!=3"
                #con="ngModel"
                [options]="itemProperty.options"
                [(ngModel)]="row.Modules"
                [filter]="itemProperty.options&&itemProperty.options.length>5"
                (onChange)="editItem(row,con,false,$event,true)" >
```

Comment: I know dataTable is deprecated, but I must use it.

Comment: Deleting appendTo="body" had no effect.